# Reassigning input connectors for HDA ATI SB (Intel HDA / Realtek ALC883) soundcard

Tags: linux, audio

My soundcard has three input connectors at the back: green, orange and black.
Usually I have them connected with my front, read and subwoofer speakers.
Sometimes though I want to reassign them to be e.g. subwoofer, rear and line-in.
Auto-detection fails here as it cannot possibly distinguish between my read and front speakers.

Windows has a nice control panel that lets me setup each connector to a certain function but I cannot find anything for Linux. Any ideas?

To clarify, if I use crawl under the table and switch the cables, everything works fine. It's just that want to do the same via software if only because it is possible :)